# Reverse geocoding of Pandas DataFrame with Lat/Long columns

Tags: python, pandas, data-frame, reverse-geocoding, geopy

I have a `DataFrame` with Lat/Long coordinates in separate series. I am trying to use GeoPy and Nominatim to get the reverse raw address. I keep getting errors such as:

> TypeError: reverse() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

or

> needs coordinate pair or Point

Here is some sample data as a test DataFrame:

```
Id  Latitude    Longitude
1   30.197535   -97.662015
2   34.895699   -82.218903
3   33.6367 -84.428101
4   33.6367 -84.428101
5   32.733601   -117.19
```

and here is my code:

```py
# summarize travelers by country using geopy geocoder

# initialize Nominatim API 
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="http")

#check the dtypes, they're float
test.dtypes

# combine lat/long into new column
test['geom'] = (test["Latitude"].map(str) + ',' + test['Longitude'].map(str)
check first record
test['geom'][0]
                
# alternative approach #1
test['geom'] = test['Latitude'].apply(str) + "," + test['Longitude'].apply(str)
test['geom'][0]

# reverse geocode
test['address'] = geolocator.reverse(test['Latitude'],test['Longitude']).raw
```

What am I doing wrong? I am new to this and it is infuriating. All examples I've found don't work or only show geocoding with one record.

Examples:

- https://towardsdatascience.com/reverse-geocoding-in-python-a915acf29eb6 (<--Can't get RateLimiter portion to work).
- https://chrisalbon.com/code/python/data_wrangling/geocoding_and_reverse_geocoding/?msclkid=78ebb2ebaf1c11ecaa56bade4a7bc240
- [https://pythonsimplified.com/geocoding-in-python-using-geopy/#:~:text=For%20reverse%20geocoding%2C%20you%20need%20to%20call%20the,can%20see%20below.%20location%20%3D%20geolocator.reverse%28%2233.76326745%2C%20-84.39511726814364%22%29%20print%28location.address%29?msclkid=f3cd8b28af1911ec95644d00f5176d17](https://pythonsimplified.com/geocoding-in-python-using-geopy/#:%7E:text=For%20reverse%20geocoding%2C%20you%20need%20to%20call%20the,can%20see%20below.%20location%20%3D%20geolocator.reverse%28%2233.76326745%2C%20-84.39511726814364%22%29%20print%28location.address%29?msclkid=f3cd8b28af1911ec95644d00f5176d17)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the [Nominatim](https://nominatim.org/) geocoder (free to choose) from the GeoPy geocoding Python library was used, for more details, please check [the documentation](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#nominatim).

Coordinates of point features should be passed as a pair ([see this thread for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57770044/valueerror-must-be-a-coordinate-pair-or-point)), otherwise, you may get this error:

> ValueError: Must be a coordinate pair or Point.

Therefore `from geopy.point import Point` was additionally imported.

The code below also uses the [`vectorize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) of NumPy.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
from geopy.point import Point

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="test")

def reverse_geocoding(lat, lon):
    try:
        location = geolocator.reverse(Point(lat, lon))
        return location.raw['display_name']
    except:
        return None

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3,4,5],
                   'Latitude': [30.197535, 34.895699, 33.636700, 33.636700, 32.733601],
                   'Longitude': [-97.662015, -82.218903, -84.428101, -84.428101, -117.190000]
                    })

df['address'] = np.vectorize(reverse_geocoding)(df['Latitude'], df['Longitude'])

print(df)
```

will result in:

```
   id   Latitude   Longitude                                            address
0   1  30.197535  -97.662015  Austin-Bergstrom International Airport, 3600, ...
1   2  34.895699  -82.218903  Greenville-Spartanburg International Airport, ...
2   3  33.636700  -84.428101  Hartsfield–Jackson Atlanta International Airpo...
3   4  33.636700  -84.428101  Hartsfield–Jackson Atlanta International Airpo...
4   5  32.733601 -117.190000  San Diego International Airport, North Harbor ...
```

Answer (score 3):

A solution:

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
locator = Nominatim(user_agent="myGeocoder")
print(test)
    id   Latitude   Longitude
0   1  30.197535  -97.662015
1   2  34.895699  -82.218903
2   3  33.636700  -84.428101
3   4  33.636700  -84.428101
4   5  32.733601 -117.190000

# combine lat/long into new column -> tuples of strings
test['geom'] = test.apply(lambda row: (str(row.Latitude),str(row.Longitude)),axis=1)
print(test.geom[0])
('30.197535', '-97.662015')

# apply locator to each row
test['address'] = test.apply(lambda row: locator.reverse(row.geom).address,axis=1)
print(test)
   id   Latitude   Longitude            geom              address                                         
0   1  30.197535  -97.662015  (30.197535, -97.662015)  Austin-Bergstrom International Airport, 3600,...
1   2  34.895699  -82.218903  (34.895699, -82.218903)  Greenville-Spartanburg International Airport,...
2   3  33.636700  -84.428101    (33.6367, -84.428101)  Hartsfield–Jackson Atlanta International Airp...
3   4  33.636700  -84.428101    (33.6367, -84.428101)  Hartsfield–Jackson Atlanta International Airp...
4   5  32.733601 -117.190000     (32.733601, -117.19)  San Diego International Airport, North Harbor...
```

Or directly without tuples of string ([How to use Geopy to geocode locations](https://www.linuxfordevices.com/tutorials/geopy-geocode-locations-python))

```
test['address'] = test.apply(lambda row: locator.reverse((row.Latitude,row.Longitude)).address,axis=1)
```

Comment: I have two questions:                     
1. How do you pass the other arguments (such as language, timeout, exactly_one, e.t.c) to the reverse method?                                                2. How do you ensure that only the country's name is returned?

Answer (score 2):

The member function [`reverse()`](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#geopy.geocoders.Nominatim.reverse) requires a list or tuple for the first parameter. So your line should look something like this:

```py
test['address'] = geolocator.reverse((test['Latitude'], test['Longitude'])).raw
```