# "ValueError: Point coordinates must be finite." when reverse geocoding in DataFrame using GeoPy

Tags: python, coordinates, data-frame, reverse-geocoding, geopy

I'm making a script in Python that takes the coordinates in a `DataFrame`, looks for the address and writes it in the `DataFrame`.

My `DataFrame` for testing purposes: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tSnNXO5MWemWw6FrhPFrO3lydMtrSAp_/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=107930029265590494426&rtpof=true&sd=true

```py
#Coordinates Reverse

import pandas as pd
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

tabelasitesrem = pd.read_excel('Sites sob estudo para remanejamento.xlsx')

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="http")

# combine lat/long into new column -> tuples of strings

county = []

for row in range(len(tabelasitesrem)):
    county.append(geolocator.reverse((tabelasitesrem['LATITUDE'][row], tabelasitesrem['LONGITUDE'][row])))
    
tabelasistesrem.insert(index, 'county', county, True)
```

However, when I run the script I get two errors

- the `DataFrame` has 100 lines plus the script stops at line 47
- address is not written in `DataFrame`.

Can you give me a solution tip?

The error:

```
File "C:\Users\Bruno\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopy\geocoders\nominatim.py", line 350, in reverse
    lat, lon = self._coerce_point_to_string(query).split(',')

  File "C:\Users\Bruno\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopy\geocoders\base.py", line 300, in _coerce_point_to_string
    point = Point(point)

  File "C:\Users\Bruno\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopy\point.py", line 175, in __new__
    return cls.from_sequence(seq)

  File "C:\Users\Bruno\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopy\point.py", line 472, in from_sequence
    return cls(*args)

  File "C:\Users\Bruno\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopy\point.py", line 188, in __new__
    _normalize_coordinates(latitude, longitude, altitude)

  File "C:\Users\Bruno\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopy\point.py", line 63, in _normalize_coordinates
    raise ValueError('Point coordinates must be finite. %r has been passed '

ValueError: Point coordinates must be finite. (nan, nan, 0.0) has been passed as coordinates.


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Bruno\Documents\Python Scripts\Sites Remanejamento.py", line 20, in <module>
    county.append(geolocator.reverse((tabelasitesrem['LATITUDE'][row], tabelasitesrem['LONGITUDE'][row])))

  File "C:\Users\Bruno\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\geopy\geocoders\nominatim.py", line 352, in reverse
    raise ValueError("Must be a coordinate pair or Point")

ValueError: Must be a coordinate pair or Point
```

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, as was pointed by @user2856, there is one record that voids the error. This record possesses `Nan` values in `"LATITUDE"` and `"LONGITUDE"` attributes.

To see these values apply the following code:

```py
nan_ = tabelasitesrem[tabelasitesrem["LATITUDE"].isnull() | tabelasitesrem["LONGITUDE"].isnull()]
print(nan_)

   UF SIGLA  LATITUDE  LONGITUDE
47      RJ9       NaN        NaN
```

Another solution could be almost the same as was demonstrated in [ValueError: Must be a coordinate pair or Point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57770044/valueerror-must-be-a-coordinate-pair-or-point) i.e. wrapping coordinates in the [`Point`](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#geopy.point.Point) class. However, it lacks the [try/except-statement](https://pythonbasics.org/try-except/)  to handle and catch errors.

So, your code may look like this:

```py
county = []
errors = []

for row in range(len(tabelasitesrem)):
    try:
        point = Point(tabelasitesrem['LATITUDE'][row], tabelasitesrem['LONGITUDE'][row])
        location = geolocator.reverse(point)
        county.append(location)
    except ValueError as error:
        print(f"There is something wrong with this location {row}")
        print(f"The following error occurred: {error}")
        errors.append(row)
```

Which will give you:

> There is something wrong with this location 47
>
> The following error occurred: Point coordinates must be finite. (nan, nan, 0.0) has been
> passed as coordinates.

And also two lists:

- `county` with valid answers
- `errors` with invalid input records

Otherwise, you may at the beginning read you Excel file without `#NV` values using the arguments `na_filter, keep_default_na, na_values` of the [`read_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html#pandas-read-excel) method.

To write the result into DataFrame use one of the solution in this thread: [Reverse geocoding of Pandas DataFrame with Lat/Long columns](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/427341/reverse-geocoding-of-pandas-dataframe-with-lat-long-columns)

Answer (score 1):

Row 49 in your spreadsheet is invalid

> `RJ9    #N/A    #N/A`

Which is element/index 47 in your dataframe:

```
tabelasitesrem.iloc[47]
Out[4]: 
UF SIGLA     RJ9
LATITUDE     NaN
LONGITUDE    NaN
```

Just [drop `NaN` values](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) when you read the xlsx. You'll also need to reset the index as you are accessing the rows by index in your code:

```
tabelasitesrem = pd.read_excel(xlsx).dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
```